# Prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $D_4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is generated by $a$ and $b$ satisfying the relators $a^4$, $b^2$, $(ab)^2$.

Let $a = (123)$ and $b = (12)$. It can be solved that $a^4=e$, $b^2=e$, and $(ab)^2=e$. So there is an epimorphism phi that maps $G$ to $D_4$ (Van Dyck's Theorem). What is this order of G is greater or equal to order of D4?

Can anyone help on the procedure, the next step l think is to show that phi is one to one so that $G$ is isomorphic to $D_4$? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: the relator $(ab)^2$ allows you to put the elements of the group in the form $a^ib^j$. Use this to give an upper bound on the order of the group.

Comment: Perhaps that you meant to write $a=(1234)$. After all, $(123)^4=(123)$.

Comment: Is b = (12) right?

Comment: @RomeoAlma No, $\langle (1234),(12)\rangle=S_4$.

Answer (score 1):

This is Theorem $1.1$ in [K. Conrad's notes](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwiF9oaF1JzWAhUCYVAKHSicAEYQFghIMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgrouptheory%2Fdihedral2.pdf&usg=AFQjCNExft8iJ2-3luuioMN8NO5LaOhJVg), which are a very good reference for dihedral groups. The proof there is for all $D_n$, $n\ge 3$, and is very detailed. It is shown that
$$\langle a,b\rangle=\{e,a,a^2,\ldots ,a^{n-1},a^2b,a^3b,\ldots,a^{n-1}b\}$$
has $2n$ elements, and an isomorphism to $D_n$ is constructed.

One may realize $D_4$ as a subgroup of $S_4$ in various ways, e.g., by
$$
a=(1234),\; b=(14)(23),
$$
see [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915249/subgroups-of-symmetric-groups-isomorphic-to-dihedral-group).